# Swift app crashing without any errors?

Tags: swift

I have an app in Swift. I have a view controller:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  SwiftUIPickerFormatted
//
//  Created by Codepixl
//  Copyright (c) 2014
//

import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var chapterPicker: UIPickerView!
    let chapterData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
    let lessonData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    let classData = ["Pre Algebra","Algebra 1"]
    var data = ["ade","01","01"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"puffin://")!) == true){
            println("Can open Puffin links")
        }else{
            showPuffinAlert()
        }
        chapterPicker.delegate = self
        chapterPicker.dataSource = self

    }

    //MARK: - Delegates and datasources
    //MARK: Data Sources

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if(component == 0){
            return classData.count
        }else if(component == 1){
            return chapterData.count
        }else if(component == 2){
            return lessonData.count
        }
        return 1
    }

    //MARK: Delegates
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        if(component == 0){
            return classData[row]
        }else if(component == 1){
            return "Chapter " + String(chapterData[row])
        }else if(component == 2){
            return "Lesson " + String(lessonData[row])
        }
        return "Error!"
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if(component == 0){
            if(row == 0){
                data[0] = "ade"
            }else if(row == 1){
                data[0] = "ate"
            }
        }else if(component == 1 || component == 2){
            if(row+1 < 10){
                data[component] = "0"+String(row+1)
            }else{
                data[component] = String(row+1)
            }
        }
        println("puffin://www.phschool.com/webcodes10/index.cfm?wcprefix=\(data[0])&wcsuffix=\(data[1])\(data[2])&area=view")
    }
    func showPuffinAlert(){
        var createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()

        createAccountErrorAlert.delegate = self

        createAccountErrorAlert.title = "Oops!"
        createAccountErrorAlert.message = "It seems you do not have the Puffin web browser installed, which is required for this app to work. You can go ahead, but be aware the video and textbook links will not work."
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("I understand- Proceed.")
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("I'll download Puffin for free.")

        createAccountErrorAlert.show()
    }

    func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){

        switch buttonIndex{

        case 0:
            NSLog("Proceed");
            break
        case 1:
            NSLog("DL");
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/puffin-academy/id716707933?mt=8#")!)
            break
        default:
            NSLog("Default");
            break
            //Some code here..

        }
    }
    @IBAction func GoVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"puffin://www.phschool.com/webcodes10/index.cfm?wcprefix=\(data[0])&wcsuffix=\(data[1])\(data[2])&area=view")!)
    }
}
```

And all works fine until I hit the "I understand-Proceed" or "I'll download Puffin for free" or the GoVideo button- it crashes with no error. I am completely stumped here as to what is happening...

EDIT: I have also cleared my build folder and manually deleted everything in it as well as adding a println in my app delegate and view controllers to make sure they have updated, and they have. Also the Simulator has been cleared.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the simulator?

Comment: @ShaanSingh Yes. I am also using a real iOS device too to test. The simulator and the device have the same problem.

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. Can you try rewriting the code with a UIAlertController?

Comment: I will later, but it can't be that because I've had this code for quite some time and it just stopped working recently. Also, the button in the View Controller crashes it too, before it runs anything in it's IBAction function. It just crashes and highlights the function declaration line when I press it. (GoVideo at the end)

Comment: Did the code work with Xcode betas and then stop working with the final version?

Comment: @ShaanSingh I never used any of the betas, it was working with the same version of XCode earlier today.

Comment: You have to retrace your footsteps. What code did you add today because there's probably something that you added that's causing this. Or, it could just be an Xcode bug. Xcode is having a lot of problems. Reinstalling Xcode or restarting your computer may solve something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68103/discussion-between-user3042719-and-shaan-singh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a corrupted file in your Xcode project. Just make a new project and try the code there.

Comment: A shortcut might be `rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"`